# Dialogflow Messenger Events Management

Tags: event-handling, dialogflow-es

I'm testing the dialogflow messenger events, and I am able to capture them but the result I should get according to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger) for example when I click a list elemnent should be:

```
element: {
  title: string,
  subtitle: string,
  image: {
    src: {rawUrl}
  },
  event: {
    name: string,
    parameters: {},
    languageCode: string
  },
  payload: {}
}
```

But I get this in the event:

```
{"isTrusted":false}
```

this is the way as I call it:

```
dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-list-element-clicked', function (event) {
        // Handle event
        console.log("df-list-element-clicked:" + JSON.stringify(event));
        
    });
```

Is there another way to get the information of the event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use event.detail.<<element_struction_for_respective_event>> to get the desired values from event listners.

For eg: For a chip click event listner (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#df-chip-clicked)
use foll code: dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-chip-clicked', function (event) {
console.log("df chip-> "+ event.detail.query)
});

Same event.details.<<element_structure>> can be used for different events as per your scenario.

Comment: This works - But do you know where is it documented? Not at `https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger`?